# Polynomial Kernel not PSD?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, kernel-methods

I am currently going through different Machine Learning methods on a low-level basis. Since the polynomial kernel

> K(x,z)=(1+x^T*z)^d

is one of the more commonly used kernels, I was under the assumption that this kernel must yield a positive (semi-)definite matrix for a fixed set of data {x1,...,xn}.
However, in my implementation, this seems to not be the case, as the following example shows:

```
import numpy as np    
np.random.seed(93)
x=np.random.uniform(0,1,5)
#Assuming d=1
kernel=(1+x[:,None]@x.T[None,:])
np.linalg.eigvals(kernel)
```

The output would be

```
[ 6.9463439e+00  1.6070016e-01  9.5388039e-08 -1.5821310e-08  -3.7724433e-08]
```

I'm also getting negative eigenvalues for d>2.
Am I totally misunderstanding something here? Or is the polynomia kernel simply not PSD?

EDIT: In a previous version, i used `x=np.float32(np.random.uniform(0,1,5))` to reduce computing time, which lead to a greater amount of negative eigenvalues (I believe due to numerical instabilities, as @user2357112 mentioned). I guess this is a good example that precision does matter? Since negative eigenvalues still occur, even for float64 precision, the follow-up question would then be how to avoid such numerical instabilities?

Comment: Those values are 0 up to numerical error.

Comment: Also I think you've got your transposes backward.

Comment: What would be the way to go to avoid this numerical instability?
And no, the transposed should be that way. I want to get a nxn matrix out of a nx1 vector, where the (i,j)th entry is x_i*x_j.

Comment: already helped a lot though, thanks.